# django @action decorator doesnt seem to work

Tags: python-3.x, django

Im trying to write simple crm rest api in django using viewsets, however when I use @action decorator to modify my database upon posting data, it doesnt seem to do anything

```
class PurchaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Purchases.objects.all()
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer    

@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def api_make_purchase(self, request):        
    product = Products.objects.get(product_name = request.data['product_name'])
    product.product_stock -= int(request.data['quantity'])
    product.sold_units += int(request.data['quantity'])
    product.save()
    return Response({'done': True})
```

when I query back after posting into purchases table, the product stock still stays at previous values, I dont get the response from api_make_purchase function either

Comment: does the execution reached the view function?\

Comment: I believe it doesnt start at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add serializer_class=ProductsSerializer to the @action decorator and create ProductsSerializer:

```
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], serializer_class=ProductSerializer)
```

Comment: thank you for reaching out :)
Ill check that out as soon as I get back home

Comment: Not a problem. I have tested it and the serializer is working on my end - the api view is reducing the quantity.